# Generics problem. I'm just not understanding how to make a generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I've got some XML, stored in a table.  I know what object it is supposed to Deserialize to, but I have many types of objects.

So, I've got this code, and it works, but it is very specific to 1 type of object.  I want to make it generic to accept one of many types of object.

```
Type _type = typeof(ReynoldsRCI.Services.rey_SvcApptView)

XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(_type);
object sck;

using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(_msg.RawText))
{
   using (XmlTextReader xreader = new XmlTextReader(reader))
   {
      sck = ser.Deserialize(xreader);
   }
}
```

However, what I would LOVE to have is a 1 line method call where I pass it the type of object and the text, and it would deserialize it and return it to the caller for use.  But I am completely an idiot when it comes to generics, so the code I have just isn't even compiling.

```
public T DoStuff<T>(T _type, string RawText)
{
   // Doesn't like this line.  Error "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(System.Type)' has some invalid arguments"
   XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(_type);
   object retObj;

   using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(RawText))
   {
      using (XmlTextReader xreader = new XmlTextReader(reader))
      {
         retObj = ser.Deserialize(xreader);
      }
   }

   // Doesn't like this line, either "The type or namespace name '_type' could not be found"
   return (_type)retObj;
}
```

I'm obviously missing something basic when it comes to Generics, and I can't piece it together. Can someone help me out with a quick pointer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get the type of `T`, you need to say `typeof(T)`. And at the end of your method, to cast `retObj` to an instance of `T`, you must say `(T)retObj`. Therefore

```
public T DoStuff<T>(string RawText) {
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    // details elided
    return (T)retObj;
}
```

The point is that `T` is playing the role of `int`, or `string`, or `Foo` or whatever. That is, it is the name of a type, and not an instance of `System.Type`. Thus, you can use it just like you would use the names of those other types. So

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
```

is analogous to

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
```

and

```
return (T)retObj;
```

is analogous to

```
return (Foo)retObj;
```

Think of `T` as a placeholder for a concrete type. The key here is to understand the difference between `Foo` and `typeof(Foo)` (or, said a little differently, types like `Foo` and instances of `System.Type` like `typeof(Foo)`).

Comment: It's annoying that XmlSerializer doesn't have a generics-based method, I've had to do something like this several times now

Comment: @Chris S: You can write your own factory that handles the problem in the blink of an eye. Here's a start: `class XmlSerializerFactory { public XmlSerializer CreateXmlSerializer<T>() { return new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)); } }`. Usage: `var factory = new XmlSerializerFactory(); XmlSerializer serializer = factory.CreateXmlSerializer<Foo>();`.

Comment: Okay, yeah, I'm an idiot.  I didn't need to pass in the type, since I'm specifying when calling it.  Thanks for the help with the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up generic type parameters and "normal" parameters.

```
public T DoStuff<T>(string RawText)
{ 
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    object retObj;

    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(RawText))
    {
        using (XmlTextReader xreader = new XmlTextReader(reader))
        {
            retObj = ser.Deserialize(xreader);
        }
    }

     return (T)retObj;
}
```

Do note that there is no way the compiler could *possibly* infer the type argument, so you'll have to use it as

```
string xml = ...;
Foo foo = DoStuff<Foo>(xml);
```

On another note:

1. Consider renaming the method to `XmlDeserialize` or similar.
2. Consider making this an extension-method on `string`.

Comment: I will DEFINITELY be renaming it.  I always start out code that I am uncertain about with ridiculous names so that I have to change them later when I REALLY know what they are doing.  Otherwise I'm likely to give a name like "GetObjectFromString", and then change the purpose of the method while investigating, and then never change it to be what it should be called.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a good answer but I already wrote this for you so I'm going to add it anyway.  I used LinqPad to write it so Dump() is short for Console.Writeline().

```
void Main()
{
    Testo testo = new Testo { First = "Phillip" };
    var abc = Serialize<Testo>(testo);
    abc.ToString().Dump();
}

public XDocument Serialize<T>(T obj)
{
    var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
                       {
                           Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                           Indent = true,
                           IndentChars = ("\t"),
                           OmitXmlDeclaration = false
                       };

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, settings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
    }

    var xml = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"), XElement.Parse(builder.ToString()));

    return xml;
}

public class Testo
{
    public string First;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the time Phillip.  I can't upvote any answers since I can't login with OpenID (work screws up OpenID on this site -- curiously, not on other OpenID sites.)